# reason for rav yehuda holding can't rip stitch of tunic

Tags: halacha, shabbat, talmud-gemara, amoroim

why in maccos when it is talking about hilchos shobbas and ripping the stitch on the neck hole of a tunic and opening a barrel stopper does rav yehuda hold that you can't rip the thread of the tunic but we know you can open a barrel stopper? what's the difference halachically

Comment: Hello learnerpro and welcome to mi.yodeya! Thank you for your very specific and pointed question regarding the _p'shat_ in a piece of _g'mara_. You will be likely to elicit better answers faster by referencing the _daf_ on which the discussion can be found. Consider clicking on "Register" above so you too can accrue 50 points and make comments like this!

Answer (score 2):

Learnerpro, I'm not sure if you are bothered by a specific problem, but simply:

A stitch is meant to combine two pieces of fabric permanently and the 2 sides of the stitch become 1 entity.  The barrel cover's adhesive doesn't combine it into 1 entity with the barrel since it is meant to be removed.  So you didn't create a new opening in the barrel, you just messed up the cover.

Comment: The stitches used to combine the two sides of the neck are also meant to be removed. That does not answer the question.

Comment: The tailors's kavana in this circumstance is irrelevant.  A stitch is meant for permanence.

Comment: Actually your answer is correct lefi shitas Rashi, who holds that we are talking about a brand new opening. It was never stitched - he opened a brand new hole. Lefi R"T (brought in Ritva) it has nothing to with kavana or normal use in either case. Rather, stitches actually make the two sides one entity as we see by shatnez that stitches even combine two separate garments to be considered one. The teet used for the magufes havis does not actually fuse the heres of the magufes to the heres of the havis in the sense of making the two one entity.

Comment: According to R"T  an interesting question would be if he glued the magufes with clay. Would it now be considered chibur?